# What is the math behind the ability for computers to grade homework?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

User Par, has given me a great answer to the question.

I know that I wrote a poorly asked question, and now understand that I should ask about machine learning. I thought there was some deep mathematics behind the ability for a computer to grade an essay; I was wrong.   What I want to ask about is the mathematics that allows computers to learn.  The only term I knew before Par gave a great answer, was AI.  Searching for AI on the internet, mostly tells me about a movie with Will Smith.  I know this is not a detailed mathematics question about some function; however, I don't really know where to start to read about the mathematics that is used to make computers learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere reputable will use a computer to mark an assignment that is qualitative (e.g. an English essay).

Computers are frequently used to mark homework in these scenarios:

1. Multiple choice questions.
2. Questions that have numerical answers (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LON-CAPA).
3. Programming assignments where the user is given boiler-plate code and asked to fill in the remainder (courses on http://www.coursera.org use this method).

Sometimes, machine learning techniques are used to verify if a student has plagiarized (e.g. http://www.turnitin.com/).

Also, this is off-topic (-1).

**Edit**: Removed my downvote in response to the author's clarification.

Comment: I know it uses computers, but there has to be some mathematics behind the operations, just hoping to get some terms to search for to read up, other than AI.  When I search for AI, I mostly get stories but haven't found anything that tells me about the mathematics that is used in AI.

Comment: The math behind machine learning would be what to learn for more exotic systems like those that check for plaigarism. Everything else that I described above uses pretty much no math. (2) just checks to see if the absolute error between a submitted answer and the solution on the server-side are within some tolerance, and (1) just checks for equivalence.

Comment: Thanks, could you suggest a introduction book to read about the topic.

Comment: Depends on your math knowledge. http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738 is a pretty good introduction, but if you want a really soft introduction, I would take Andrew Ng's course on coursera.org: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml